# How to create map between IQueryCollection to any type?

Tags: .net-core, azure-functions, automapper

I have a Azure Function that receive IQueryCollection parameter and I need to convert (with automapper) to any object.

From this example query string...

http://localhost:7071/api/v1/get?id=xxxx&name=xxxx

...I want to map to this type:

```cs
public class Person
{
   public int Id {get;set;}
   public string Name {get;set;}
}
```

I use mapping like this:

```cs
var response = await personService.GetPerson(_mapper.Map<Person>(request.GetQueryParameterDictionary()));
```

*request.GetQueryParameterDictionary() returns IDictionary*

I tested this maps (but not works):

```cs
CreateMap<IQueryCollection, Person>();
CreateMap<KeyValuePair<string, StringValues>, Person>();
CreateMap<IDictionary<string, string>, Person>();
```

Comment: Why do you need automapper for two parameters ?

Comment: This is only an example, I have a big query string with many parameters

Comment: http://docs.automapper.org/en/latest/Dynamic-and-ExpandoObject-Mapping.html

Comment: But... how can configure Automapper Profile?

Comment: There is a section in the docs that explains configuring a profile: http://docs.automapper.org/en/stable/Configuration.html

Comment: Hi @MikeBovenlander On my question you can see profiles, but not working between IQueryCollection and custom type. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

It's not an ideal thing, but you could use `JsonConvert` to serialize/deserialize to any type you want.

```
var query = context.Request.Query; // this is IQueryCollection
var json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(query.ToDictionary(q => q.Key, q => q.Value.ToString()));
var person = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Person>(json);
```

Answer (score -1):

What you are missing is the mapping for the specific type.
Auto mapper by default tries to map properties by their name only.

Since you are trying to map from a specific query parameter to a specific property, you'll need to tell the `profile` how to do so:

```cs
this.CreateMap<IQueryCollection, Person>()
    .ForMember(person => person.Id, expression => expression.MapFrom(query => int.Parse(query["id"][0])))
    .ForMember(person => person.Name, expression => expression.MapFrom(query => query["name"][0]));
```

But, if you want to create a generic mapper, to support actually **any** type, you'll have to do a lot of work.

You'll have to use reflection to go over all the properties of the target and find their value in the query collection. **And in addition**, you'll have to convert them from string to their actual value.

Here is the start of what you'll have to do inside your AutoMapper `Profile`:

```cs
CreateMap<IQueryCollection, Person>()
    .ForAllMembers(expression =>
    {
        // Check that the name exists in the query collection
        string name = expression.DestinationMember.Name.ToLower();
        expression.PreCondition(query => query.ContainsKey(name));

        // AutoMapper usually supports only properties
        PropertyInfo destinationProperty = expression.DestinationMember as PropertyInfo;
        if (destinationProperty == null)
            return;

        // Convert different types.
        // Continue the below pattern for each type you want to map.
        if (destinationProperty.PropertyType == typeof(string))
        {
            expression.MapFrom(query => query[name][0]);
        }
        else if (destinationProperty.PropertyType == typeof(int))
        {
            expression.MapFrom(query => int.Parse(query[name][0]));
        }
    });
```

### Result

For a route: https://localhost:7071/api/test?id=5&name=alex
And for the code:

```cs
[FunctionName("QueryCollectionTest")]
public IActionResult QueryCollectionTest(
    [HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Anonymous, "get", Route = "test")] HttpRequest req)
{

    Person person = _mapper.Map<Person>(req.Query);
    return new OkResult();
}
```

I've got this mapped:

[image]

Side note:
With C# 8 you could use [patterns](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/do-more-with-patterns-in-c-8-0/) to make the above code nicer, but that's a answer for another question. :)

Comment: Thanks, but I'm not sure that is suitable solution because you need validate every types, nullables, etc...

Comment: Well, yes! That's exactly the problem. Value types in C# cannot be dynamically mapped from other types. You can see an example of this in every other .Net library.  The LINQ is a great example for that. Have a look at how Sum, Min, Max and others are implemented: https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Core/System/Linq/Enumerable.cs,17ae8142727f08ee,references

Answer (score -1):

Finally, I created a method like this:

```cs
public static class HttpRequestMapper
{
    public static T Query<T>(IQueryCollection collection)
    {
        var instance = Activator.CreateInstance<T>();

        foreach (var property in instance.GetType().GetProperties())
        {
           foreach (var item in collection)
           {
              if (item.Key == property.Name)
              {
                 if (property.PropertyType == typeof(Guid) || property.PropertyType == typeof(Guid?))
                    property.SetValue(instance, new Guid(item.Value));

                 if (property.PropertyType == typeof(DateTime) || property.PropertyType == typeof(DateTime?))
                     property.SetValue(instance, Convert.ToDateTime(item.Value));

                 if (property.PropertyType == typeof(string))
                     property.SetValue(instance, item.Value.ToString());

                 if (property.PropertyType == typeof(int) || property.PropertyType == typeof(int?))
                     property.SetValue(instance, int.Parse(item.Value));

                 if (property.PropertyType == typeof(decimal) || property.PropertyType == typeof(decimal?))
                     property.SetValue(instance, decimal.Parse(item.Value));

                 if (property.PropertyType == typeof(long) || property.PropertyType == typeof(long?))
                     property.SetValue(instance, long.Parse(item.Value));

                 if (property.PropertyType == typeof(bool) || property.PropertyType == typeof(bool?))
                     property.SetValue(instance, bool.Parse(item.Value));
                 }

                }
            }

            return instance;

    }
}
```